# Cyberduck uploads break node-dev/up/hotnode

Tags: node.js, cyberduck

I've been using Cyberduck 4.2.1 to connect to my EC2 instance to edit my Node projects.  I've used [Node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) to reload my project/server as files are updated, but if I save the files through Cyberduck's Edit command, the server never really reloads and usually crashes.

I've tested with a few different editors (TextMate, Dashcode) with the same result.  Node-dev restarts correctly when I edit files from the terminal.  I have tried a few others that do rougly the same thing, [hotnode](https://github.com/saschagehlich/hotnode) and [up](https://github.com/learnboost/up).  They all work when editing via Terminal, but fail when I edit files through Cyberduck.  I think it has something to do with the way Cyberduck replaces the remote files when it is saved.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and maybe suggest some changes to these github projects?  If not, are there better Mac FTP clients that might not have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Node-dev, but my educated guess is that it crashes because it reads a partially uploaded file. I suggest to try the [Upload with temporary filename](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/upload#TransfersGeneralUploadsUploadwithtemporaryfilename) feature available as a hidden option in Cyberduck.

Comment: You were right, uploading with a temporary filename fixes this issue.  The link itself with the terminal command did not work though.  Luckily, it is no longer a hidden preference.  The checkbox "Upload with temporary filename" is in the Transfers tab of Preferences.

Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try CyberDuck 6.6.2 ....It works for me